# UNIX_TIMESTAMP incorrect result

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to check date + 1 month from DB with correct date. I try:

```
$todayDate = date("Y-m-d");
$dateOneMonthAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todayDate)) . "+1 month");

$result = mysql_query('SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date") AS date FROM followform WHERE id = "28"') or die(mysql_error());  
$date = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($dateOneMonthAdded == $date['date']) echo 'nice';
```

But $date['date'] == 0

If I use - `mysql_query('SELECT date FROM followform WHERE id = "28"')`

```
$date['date'] == 2012-08-13
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: @MichaelYounani: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110645/172011)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP("date")` should be `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`. With the quotes in there, it's trying to convert the literal string "date" to a timestamp.

Comment: Nice. But now $date['date'] == 1344578400. And 1344578400 != $dateOneMonthAdded

Comment: Well what is `$dateOneMonthAdded`? Are you sure it's correct? Are you sure record 28 is exactly one month ahead of the current date (to the second)?

Answer (score 2):

Remove double quotes `"` from `unix_timestamp` function in your query. It should be:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS date FROM followform WHERE id = "28"
```